# You have an error in your SQL syntax [MariaDB]

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl, mariadb

I'm getting this error while developing a javaEE application with MariaDB.

The error is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'STARTING DATE, TITLE VARCHAR(255), CREATOR VARCHAR(255), LOCATION BIGINT, FORECA' at line 1

This is the problematic query:

```
CREATE TABLE EVENT 
(
   ID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
   DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(255), 
   ENDING DATE, 
   ISALLDAY TINYINT(1) default 0, 
   PUBLICEVENT TINYINT(1) default 0, 
   STARTING DATE, 
   TITLE VARCHAR(255), 
   CREATOR VARCHAR(255), 
   LOCATION BIGINT, 
   FORECAST BIGINT, 
   PRIMARY KEY (ID);
```

I can't figure out what is the problem...

Comment: You are missing the closing `)`

Comment: Thank you, that actually was only a copy-paste error, but helped to figure out the main problem: starting is a reserved keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a two typos:

1. STARTING - is a reserved word - use backticks
2. you forget closing parenthesis

This script should work:

```
CREATE TABLE EVENT 
(
   ID VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
   DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(255), 
   ENDING DATE, 
   ISALLDAY TINYINT(1) default 0, 
   PUBLICEVENT TINYINT(1) default 0, 
   `STARTING` DATE, 
   TITLE VARCHAR(255), 
   CREATOR VARCHAR(255), 
   LOCATION BIGINT, 
   FORECAST BIGINT, 
   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```